# Atualização de valores de um objeto de uma coleção via Binding WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Seguindo modelo MVVM, não estou conseguindo atualizar os valores de uma variável de um objeto em uma coleção, mostra-los na tela ou o usuário digitar e este valor ser passado para a variável.

No meu caso, tenho uma tela de cadastro de clientes e este cliente pode conter mais de um endereço. Pois bem, um controle do tipo `ItemsControl` recebe no atributo `ItemsSource`  o `Binding` da coleção `Endereços` e no atributo `DataTemplate` o layout de cada `ItemControl(endereço)` e cada campo com seu respectivo `Binding`.

Segue os códigos para melhor entendimento:

> ViewModel

```
public class ClienteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ClienteViewModel()
        {
            Enderecos = new ObservableCollection<EnderecoViewModel>();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<EnderecoViewModel> _enderecos;

        public ObservableCollection<EnderecoViewModel> Enderecos
        {
            get { return _enderecos; }
            set
            {
                _enderecos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

> XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Enderecos, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type endereco:EnderecoViewModel}">
                                <TextBlock Text="CEP:"/>
                                <xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="00000-000" TextChanged="TbCep_OnTextChanged" Text="{Binding Cep}" Tag="{Binding EnderecoId}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Logradouro"/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Logradouro}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Número:" />
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Numero}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

> XAML.cs

```
private void TbCep_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var enderecoOnList =
                _clienteViewModel.Enderecos.FirstOrDefault(
                    x =>
                        x.EnderecoId == Guid.Parse(sender.GetType().GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(sender).ToString()));


            var endereco = new Endereco();
            if (enderecoOnList != null && enderecoOnList.Cep != null)
            {
                var cep = enderecoOnList.Cep.Replace("-", "");
                if (cep.Length == 8)
                {
                            endereco = BuscarEnderecoPorCep(cep);
                            if (endereco != null)
                            {
                                enderecoOnList.Logradouro = endereco.Logradouro;
                                enderecoOnList.Complemento = endereco.Complemento;
                                enderecoOnList.Bairro = endereco.Bairro;
                                enderecoOnList.Cidade = endereco.Cidade;
                                enderecoOnList.Estado = endereco.Estado;
                                enderecoOnList.CodigoIbge = endereco.CodigoIbge;
                                enderecoOnList.Pais = "Brasil";
                            }
                }
            }
        }
```

Quando este evento `"TbCep_OnTextChanged"` é acionado, a variável `enderecoOnList` recebe o endereço da posição certa, mas todas as variáveis estão setadas como `null`, inclusive o CEP digitado pelo usuário na tela.

Quando altero qualquer variável de um objeto endereço via tela, a coleção Endereços não recebe este valor naquela posição ou em outra posição da coleção.

NOTA-SE: Tenho um botão adicionar, que adiciona um novo objeto endereço a coleção Endereços e ocorre o Binding normalmente na tela. Tenho também um botão remover, que remove um objeto endereço da coleção Endereços, que funciona também perfeitamente. Ou seja, o binding ligado a Endereços funciona, porém o Binding ligado a uma variável de um objeto endereços da coleção Endereços não funciona.

Como posso solucionar este meu problema, já tentei setar o Mode do Binding como TwoWay, mas ainda não obtive sucesso, ou o que arrumar em meu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom pessoal, eu consegui resolver este meu problema depois de algum tempo a mais de estudo. Como próprio citei na pergunta acima, o `Binding` na coleção `Endereços` funcionava perfeitamente, que ao mesmo tempo em seus filhos `endereço` não ocorrerá o `Binding` de suas variáveis. Pensando e focando neste problema, podemos notar que cada filho `endereço` também precisará implementar a classe  `INotifyPropertyChanged` e chamar o método `OnPropertyChanged` que é acionado para atualização da propriedade na tela. Onde eu não o fazia anteriormente.

Segue o código da classe `endereço`

> ViewModel

```
public class CreateClienteEnderecoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CreateClienteEnderecoViewModel()
        {
            EnderecoId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        #region Properties
        public Guid EnderecoId { get; set; }

        private string _logradouro;
        public string Logradouro
        {
            get { return _logradouro; }
            set
            {
                _logradouro = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _numero;
        public string Numero
        {
            get { return _numero; }
            set
            {
                _numero = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Espero ajudar mais pessoas, pois demorei a encontrar uma solução passível a este problema! Obrigado!